# Simile timeline - Reading from database without using XML?

Tags: xml, database, timeline, simile

Does anyone have any thoughts about making Simile read data from a database without using XML? Or is XML definitely the way to go. I'd like to hear about possible alternatives and opinions around what would be the most optimal solution.

The data I will be using are basically just coordinates and geographical names, as well as some small integers.

I would very much appreciate any input here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sometimes like to use json format for data that is not overly complicated or nested, and I think that could be good for this as well.